# select second 50% of a table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2017

I want to select **second 50%** of a table **I mean 50% to 100%** , not this :

Select top (50) percent *
from Production.Product  -- this gave me the first 50% of Table

*and i don't have a specific column for counting rows and i need to use top , count, etc , please help me write the code*

**I'm using Microsoft SQL server**

Comment: How do you know what rows are the "top" or "bottom" 50%? What ordering are you using?

Comment: Sure we can ***help***. What do you have so far?

Comment: Show us how you select the "first 50 %" then we may help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use operator except for take all rows except 50 % first rows, but you should be use a order by any column ;)

```
select * from yourtable 
except
select top 50 percent * from yourtable
```